# Mouseout event in jQuery is triggered when my tooltip is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

I have this menu that adds a

[image]

It has this jQuery code to add a class on hover and remove on mouse-out like this below...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.actions-menu').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).find('.actions-list').show();
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.actions-list').hide();
 });
});
```

The problem is in this image below, when a button icon in the popover menu is hovered over, it shows a tooltip.  When you hover this tooltip it triggers the mouseout in my code above and closes the menu.

I need the menu to stay open if a tool tip with CSS CLass  `.hastip` is hovered as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the HTML markup?

Comment: @epascarello https://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/xRoERe?editors=0111

Answer (score 1):

All you need is nested `.actions-list` inside `.actions-menu` (if it possible).

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBPLNK

Comment: You can see my demo here to see the problem https://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/xRoERe?editors=0101 when you open the dropdown and hover the tooltip it closes

Comment: I think problem is your `tipsy` element was appended to body, so when your mouse move over tool tip `mouseout` will be triggered (because `tipsy`  element stay outside of `.hastip`) element. The idea is you may try to use `appendTo(this.$element)` instead of `appendTo(document.body)`, I try it already but tooltip doesn't display maybe you need to modify CSS or inline style to make it able to display event tooltip was inserted inside `.hastip` element.